# Program Buttons Not Working

Tags: java, button, sudoku

I have been writing a sudoku program, and I can't seem to get some of the buttons working properly. Here's my code for creating the display

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Display extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int dispWidth = 557;
    private int dispHeight = 580;
    private int buttonWidth = 200;
    private final Color MY_GREEN = new Color(0, 153, 0); 
    private final Color MY_BLUE = new Color(0, 102, 204);
    private final Color MY_PURPLE = new Color(148, 0, 211);

    public Display() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {
                selectNumber(m.getX(), m.getY());
            }
        });
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel button = new JPanel(); // Button panel
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, dispHeight));
        button.setBackground(MY_GREEN);
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        flowLayout.setVgap(55); // Creates symetry
        flowLayout.setHgap(100); // See above
        button.setLayout(flowLayout);
        Buttons enter = new Buttons("Enter Your Own", "enter");
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        button.add(enter);
        Buttons startHard = new Buttons("Start - Hard", "startHard");
        startHard.addActionListener(this);
        button.add(startHard);
        Buttons startMedium = new Buttons("Start - Medium", "startMedium");
        startMedium.addActionListener(this);
        button.add(startMedium);
        Buttons startEasy = new Buttons("Start - Easy", "startEasy");
        startEasy.addActionListener(this);
        button.add(startEasy);
        Buttons goBack = new Buttons("Go Back One", "goBack");
        goBack.addActionListener(this);
        button.add(goBack);
        Buttons solve = new Buttons("Solve It", "solve");
        solve.addActionListener(this);
        button.add(solve);
        this.add(button, BorderLayout.WEST); // Adds the button panel to the general display panel
    }

    private void selectNumber(int x, int y) {
        int numPos[] = {3,63,124,187,248,309,372,433,494};
        final byte SPACING = 19; // For spacing the numbers out evenly
        if(x < buttonWidth + numPos[0])
            return; // Returns nothing if it's not in the sudoku playing area
        x -= buttonWidth - numPos[0];
        byte count; // For use in loops
        byte xPos = 0;
        for(count = 0; count < 9; count++) { // Finds x position
            if(x > numPos[count])
                xPos = count;
        }
        byte yPos = 0; 
        for(count = 0; count < 9; count++) { // Finds y position
            if(y > numPos[count])
                yPos = count;
        }
        byte position = (byte) (xPos + yPos*9); // The number position of 0-80
        byte xNum = 0;
        x -= numPos[xPos];
        for(count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
            if(x > SPACING * count)
                xNum = count;
        }
        byte yNum = 0;
        y -=  numPos[yPos]; 
        for(count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
            if(y >  SPACING * count)
                yNum = count;
        }
        byte number = (byte) (xNum + yNum*3);
        MyGame.i = (byte) Methods.select(MyGame.b, number, position, MyGame.i);
        repaint(buttonWidth, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight); // Redraws the board
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(dispWidth + buttonWidth, dispHeight);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        final byte FOOT = 24;
        final byte NUM_X = 11;
        final byte NUM_Y = 54;
        final byte BLANK_SIZE = 59;
        final byte PENCIL_X = 4;
        final byte PENCIL_Y = 18;
        final byte S_PENCIL_X = 20;
        final byte S_PENCIL_Y = 19;
        final int FOOT_MESSAGE_X = 96;
        final int FOOT_MESSAGE_Y = 574;
        final int FOOT_NUMBER_X = 211;
        final int FOOT_NUMBER_Y = 574;
        int BigLines[] = {0, 184, 369, 554, 577};
        int SmallLines[] = {62, 123, 247, 308, 432, 493};
        int numPos[] = {3, 63, 124, 187, 248, 309, 372, 433, 494};
        Font selected = new Font("Arial", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 70);
        Font foot = new Font("Arial", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 20);
        Font pencil = new Font("Arial", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 20);
        super.paintComponent(g); //paint the component's JPanel     
        g.setColor(MY_BLUE);
        g.setFont(pencil);
        byte count;
        for(count = 0; count < 5; count++)
            g.fillRect(0, BigLines[count], dispWidth + buttonWidth, 3);
        for(count = 0; count < 6; count++)
            g.drawLine(0, SmallLines[count], dispWidth + buttonWidth, SmallLines[count]);
        g.fillRect(BigLines[0] + buttonWidth , 0, 3, dispHeight);
        g.fillRect(BigLines[1] + buttonWidth , 0, 3, dispHeight - FOOT);
        g.fillRect(BigLines[2] + buttonWidth , 0, 3, dispHeight - FOOT);
        g.fillRect(BigLines[3] + buttonWidth , 0, 3, dispHeight);
        for(count = 0; count < 6; count++)
            g.drawLine(SmallLines[count] + buttonWidth, 0, SmallLines[count] + buttonWidth, dispHeight -FOOT);
        g.setFont(foot);
        g.drawString("This is Step        in the Sudoku Solution", FOOT_MESSAGE_X + buttonWidth, FOOT_MESSAGE_Y);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(MyGame.i), FOOT_NUMBER_X + buttonWidth, FOOT_NUMBER_Y);
        byte numCount;
        for(numCount = 0; numCount < 81; numCount++) {
            g.setColor(MY_BLUE);
            byte zeros = 0;
            byte outerCount;
            for(outerCount = 0; outerCount < 3; outerCount++) {
                for(count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
                    byte pencilnumber = MyGame.b[count + outerCount*3 + numCount*9][ MyGame.i];
                    if(pencilnumber > 0) {
                        if(pencilnumber < 10) {
                            g.setFont(pencil);
                            g.drawString(String.valueOf(pencilnumber ), numPos[numCount % 9] + (count*S_PENCIL_X) + PENCIL_X + buttonWidth, numPos[numCount / 9] + outerCount * S_PENCIL_Y + PENCIL_Y);
                        } else {
                            g.setFont(selected);
                            g.drawString(String.valueOf(pencilnumber - 10), numPos[numCount % 9] + buttonWidth + NUM_X, numPos[numCount / 9] + NUM_Y);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        zeros += 1;
                }
            }
            if(zeros == 9) {
                g.setColor(MY_PURPLE);
                g.fillRect(numPos[numCount%9] + buttonWidth, numPos[numCount/9], BLANK_SIZE, BLANK_SIZE);
            }
        }
    } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {       
        if (a.getActionCommand() == "enter")
            MyGame.i = 0;
        else if (a.getActionCommand() == "startHard") {
             Methods.testBoard(MyGame.b, (byte) 0);
             MyGame.i = 20;
        } else if (a.getActionCommand() == "startMedium") {
             Methods.testBoard(MyGame.b, (byte) 0);
             MyGame.i = 35;
        } else if (a.getActionCommand() == "startEasy") {
             Methods.testBoard(MyGame.b, (byte) 0);
             MyGame.i = 50;
        } else if (a.getActionCommand() == "solve")
            Methods.testBoard(MyGame.b, MyGame.i);
        else if (a.getActionCommand() == "goBack") {
            if (MyGame.i > 0)
            MyGame.i -= 1;
        }
        repaint(buttonWidth, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
    }
}
```

And here's my methods behind the display

```
import java.util.*;

public class Methods{

    public static void startGame(byte[][] b) { // Places 1-9 in 81 spots to help create the board
        for (int q = 0; q < 729; q++)
            b[q][0] = (byte) (1 + (q%9));
    }

    public static void testBoard(byte[][] b, byte start) { // Creates the board to be played upon
        Random r = new Random();
        byte i = start;
        int numOfTrys = 0;
        do { // Keep going until there's a full board
            numOfTrys += 1;
            boolean blanks = true;
            i = start;
            while((i < 81) && (blanks)) { // Generates numbers to be run
                byte num = (byte) r.nextInt(9); // Gets an int from 0 to 8
                byte pos = (byte) r.nextInt(81);  // Gets an into from 0 to 80
                i = (byte) Methods.select(b, num, pos, i); // Determines if there's a i
                boolean alone = false;
                do { // Find any numbers that are alone
                    alone = false;
                    byte posCount;  // For numbers 0 to 80
                    byte numCount;  // For positions 0 to 8
                    for(posCount = 0; posCount < 81; posCount++) {
                        byte zeros = 0;
                        for(numCount = 0; numCount < 9; numCount++) {
                            if(b[posCount * 9 + numCount][i] == 0)
                                zeros += 1; // Adds one if the value is 0
                            else
                                num = (byte) (b[posCount * 9 + numCount][i] - 1);
                            if(zeros == 9)
                                blanks = false; // There's a dead end in the numbers (no number can be placed properly)
                        }           
                        if((zeros == 8) && (num < 10)) {
                            i = (byte) Methods.select(b, num, pos, i);
                            alone = true;
                        }
                    }
                } while(alone);
            }
            MyGame.i = i;
        } while((i != 81) && (numOfTrys < 600));  // Should never need more than 600 or so... I hope
    }

    public static int select(byte[][] b, byte num, byte pos, byte i){
        if((b[pos*9 + num][i] == 0) || (b[pos*9 + num][i] > 9))
            return i;
        i += 1;
        int count = 0;
        for(count = 0; count < 729; count++)
            b[count][i] = b[count][i - 1]; // Copies existing value to the next spot
        for(count = 0; count < 9; count++)
            b[pos*9 + count][i] = 0;
        byte row = (byte) (pos/9);
        for(count = 0; count < 9; count++)
            b[row * 81 + count * 9 + num][i] = 0; // For horizontal row
        byte column = (byte) (pos%9);
        for(count = 0; count < 9; count++)
            b[column * 9 + count * 81 + num][i] = 0; // For vertical row
        int rBlock = (pos/27)*243; // Block of 3 in a row
        int cBlock = ((pos%9)/3)*27; // Block of 3 in a column
        byte numCount;
        for(numCount = 0; numCount < 3; numCount++) {
            for(count = 0; count < 3; count++)
                b[rBlock + cBlock + count * 9 + numCount * 81 + num][i] = 0; // Creates a block of 3x3
        }
        b[pos*9 + num][i] = (byte) (num + 11); // Selected value now from 11-19. This helps distinguish numbers already used.
        return i;
    }
}
```

The button to enter your own solution and go back are working, but the buttons to start an easy, medium, or hard game aren't, as well as the button to solve what has been entered already. I think the issue is rooted testBoard, as that is what is uniquely called in the actionPerformed method for these buttons, and the two buttons working don't have any issues. The testBoard method also calls the select method. Any help would be appreciated.

There are three other files needed to run the program, so if anyone needs them to help me out, I am more than willing to provide them. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm guessing that the reason someone downvoted your question is because of the title. If you could make it less specific to your program and more specific to the type of the issue, that would help. In other words, please take out "sudoku" because the issue is not with sudoku exactly but with Java buttons. I know it's annoying when someone downvotes you and doesn't explains why.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Renamed the post.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. In the second call to select in testBoard, the variables should be (b, num, column, i), not (b, num, pos, i). The way the program was written would send it into an infinite loop, causing the buttons to not work properly.